# Heading above the table doesn't fit the resolution

Tags: html, css

I have a weekly report in HTML with two sections side by side. One section inside a `tr` has a heading above it, and there is a similar heading for section 2. I have written a simple `tr` `th` to display the headers. But now I want a **heading** placed above this table. I have written a `div` to display the heading like this:

```
<div style="float:right;width:70%; font-weight: bold">
  Weekly Recordable Incident Rate&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  Weekly Lost Time Incident Rate
</div>.
```

But this affects the resolution. When you minimize the browser the heading goes left-right.

Can anyone help me here please?

```
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
       <div style="float:right;width:70%; font-weight: bold">
          Weekly Recordable Incident Rate&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    Weekly Lost Time Incident Rate
       </div>   

       <tr>
          <th><span style='color:white;margin-right:1.00cm;'>&nbsp;</span></th>
          <th colspan="2" class="bluebg">Wk1 </th>
          <th colspan="2" class="bluebg">Wk2 </th>
          <th colspan="2" class="bluebg">Wk3 </th>
          <th colspan="2" class="bluebg">Wk4 </th>
          <th colspan="2" class="bluebg">Wk5 </th>
          <th class="whitebg">&nbsp;</th>
          <th class="bluebg">Wk2 </th>
          <th class="bluebg">Wk3 </th>
          <th class="bluebg">Wk4 </th>
          <th class="bluebg">Wk5 </th>
          <th class="bluebg">Wk6 </th>  
       </tr>

       <tr> 
          <th><span style='color:white;margin-right:2.00cm;'>&nbsp;</span></th>
          <td style="border-bottom-color: white;">Recs</td>
          <td style="border-bottom-color: white;">RIR</td>
          <td style="border-bottom-color: white;">Recs</td>
          <td style="border-bottom-color: white;">RIR</td>
          <td style="border-bottom-color: white;">Recs</td>
          <td style="border-bottom-color: white;">RIR</td>
          <td style="border-bottom-color: white;">Recs</td>
          <td style="border-bottom-color: white;">RIR</td>
          <td style="border-bottom-color: white;">Recs</td>
          <td style="border-bottom-color: white;">RIR</td>
       </tr>  

</table>
```

[image: This is good when browser is full opened]

[image: This is the problem, when maximize the browser heading get distracted]

Comment: firstly, please remove all `&nbsp;` from your code and align the text in heading using CSS. Most of your alignment issues will be solved.

Comment: I tried removing it, but no luck :(  If u look closely there are two different sections of weeks side by side, which has different headings. So only problem is when you minimize the window or zoom-out, the heading gets scattered(2nd image).

Comment: The majority of your problems come from the design of your table. You shouldn't split a table header in 2 tables. Consider creating the necessary cells using colspan and rowspan. Also, a <div> shouldn't be inside a table, outside of a <td> or <th>. The right float with the percentage width makes it impossible to control.

Answer (score 1):

u din give us all the css so i din complete it whole but plz check this one..may be it will help

```
<table border="1">
<tr height="20px;">  <td colspan="17"><div style="width:100%; font-weight: bold">
      <div style="float: right;margin: 0 auto;width: 44%; ">Weekly Recordable Incident Rate</div><div style="float: right;
    margin: 0 auto;width: 44%;">Weekly Lost Time Incident Rate</div><div style="clear:both;"></div>
   </div> </td></tr>
   <tr>
      <th><span style="color:white;margin-right:1.00cm;width:10px;">&nbsp;</span></th>
      <th colspan="2" class="bluebg">Wk1 </th>
      <th colspan="2" class="bluebg">Wk2 </th>
      <th colspan="2" class="bluebg">Wk3 </th>
      <th colspan="2" class="bluebg">Wk4 </th>
      <th colspan="2" class="bluebg">Wk5 </th>
      <th class="whitebg">&nbsp;</th>
      <th class="bluebg">Wk2 </th>
      <th class="bluebg">Wk3 </th>
      <th class="bluebg">Wk4 </th>
      <th class="bluebg">Wk5 </th>
      <th class="bluebg">Wk6 </th>  
   </tr>
   <tr> 
      <th><span style="color:white;margin-right:2.00cm;">&nbsp;</span>  </th>
      <td style="border-bottom-color: white;">Recs</td>
      <td style="border-bottom-color: white;">RIR</td>
      <td style="border-bottom-color: white;">Recs</td>
      <td style="border-bottom-color: white;">RIR</td>
      <td style="border-bottom-color: white;">Recs</td>
      <td style="border-bottom-color: white;">RIR</td>
      <td style="border-bottom-color: white;">Recs</td>
      <td style="border-bottom-color: white;">RIR</td>
      <td style="border-bottom-color: white;">Recs</td>
      <td style="border-bottom-color: white;">RIR</td>
   </tr>  
  </table>
```

and sorry as m just begginer but i hope that by this you will get the hint to get your desired solution

Comment: your idea was superb, but somehow it didnt appear to work. The heading  s coming down each other.

Comment: no..i checked that...can u send me screen shot and plz give ur table css too..thanx..as code is half so

Comment: Hey i have checked again and i checked in all diamnsions bt m nt able to find error??but if u r gettin den plz show me the screenshot..as i really want to help...:)

Comment: Yes i sent it through the answer.. pls check. let me know if you require any more detail. It means a lot.

Comment: sorry for asking but did u change the width of div from 70% to 100%?

Comment: and why you need 60% and 44%..put ur data in those..while i am working more on this..

Comment: nope. width of which div? First or second? first div width is 60 and second div width is 44..

Comment: <tr height="20px" class="extrasmalltextbold">
 <td colspan="17">
 <div style="width:100%; font-weight: bold">
<div style="float: right;margin: 0 auto;width: 60%; ">Weekly Recordable Incident Rate</div>
<div style="float: right;margin: 0 auto;width: 44%;">Weekly Lost Time Incident Rate</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
   </div> </td>

</tr>

Comment: 60 and 44 because to make it align above that weekly sections

Comment: see..you are using width  100% and den u r giving more den (60 % + 44% = 114%)..den offcourse heading will crash..bt now m creating table design for you so wanted to ask that "Weekly Lost Time Incident Rate" has same column as first table heading?

Comment: Yeah in was doing wrong. I changed it, but still no luck. So just tried the code provided by Veksen and it worked. Thanks for all your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Avinafh : When width of the div is set at 60 and 44 respectively [image: Like this]

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th colspan="10" style="text-align:center">Weekly Recordable Incident Rate</th>
    <th></th>
    <th colspan="5" style="text-align:center">Weekly Lost Time Incident Rate</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><span style='color:white;margin-right:1.00cm;'>&nbsp;</span></th>
    <th colspan="2" class="bluebg">Wk1</th>
    <th colspan="2" class="bluebg">Wk2</th>
    <th colspan="2" class="bluebg">Wk3</th>
    <th colspan="2" class="bluebg">Wk4</th>
    <th colspan="2" class="bluebg">Wk5</th>
    <th class="whitebg">&nbsp;</th>
    <th class="bluebg">Wk2</th>
    <th class="bluebg">Wk3</th>
    <th class="bluebg">Wk4</th>
    <th class="bluebg">Wk5</th>
    <th class="bluebg">Wk6</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><span style='color:white;margin-right:2.00cm;'>&nbsp;</span></th>
    <td style="border-bottom-color: white;">Recs</td>
    <td style="border-bottom-color: white;">RIR</td>
    <td style="border-bottom-color: white;">Recs</td>
    <td style="border-bottom-color: white;">RIR</td>
    <td style="border-bottom-color: white;">Recs</td>
    <td style="border-bottom-color: white;">RIR</td>
    <td style="border-bottom-color: white;">Recs</td>
    <td style="border-bottom-color: white;">RIR</td>
    <td style="border-bottom-color: white;">Recs</td>
    <td style="border-bottom-color: white;">RIR</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No problem! Make sure you vote/accept the answer if that's your solution. I also edited my answer to center the headers.